# i need to create array on the heap aby to hold a specific number set by the user

Tags: c++, arrays, file, heap-memory

hey guys new to this site looking some help for my final project i having to create a project that takes car data saves it to the heap and has a bunch of error checking not all the way done but getting there.  but i cant grasp the heap and how to input it correctly into my code here is what i have. and it has to be under 175 lines and i still have to have it ask user if they want to write to a new file or existing. thanks ahead once again question is how do i create array on the heap able to hold the number of vech specified buy user.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class carData4
{
public:

    void setYear(int& year);
    void setMake(string make);
    void setModel(string);
    void setMileage(int& mileage);
    void setName(string name);
    void setNumber(string number);
    int getYear(){ return itsYear; }
    string getMake(){ return itsMake; }
    string getModel(){ return itsModel; }
    int getMileage(){ return itsMileage; }
    string getName(){ return itsName; }
    string getNumber(){ return itsNumber; }

private:;

        int itsYear;
        string itsMake;
        string itsModel;
        int itsMileage;
        string itsName;
        string itsNumber;
};
void carData4::setYear(int & year)
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the cars Year from 1910 and 2014:\n ";
        cin >> year;
        itsYear = year;

        if (year < 1910 || year > 2014)
            cout << "INVALID! please enter a correct year! ";
    } while (year < 1910 || year > 2014);
}

void carData4::setMake(string make)
{
    cout << "Enter the cars make:\n\n";
    cin >> make;
    itsMake = make;
}
void carData4::setModel(string model)
{
    cout << "Enter the cars model:\n\n";
    cin >> model;
    itsModel = model;
}
void carData4::setMileage(int & mileage)
{
    do{
        cout << "Enter the cars mileage:\n\n";
        cin >> mileage;
        itsMileage = mileage;
    }

    while (mileage <0 || mileage >10000000);

    cout << "NOPE enter within 0 and million miles.\n\n";
    cin >> mileage;
    itsMileage = mileage;

}
void carData4::setName(string name)
{
    cout << "Enter your name :";
    cin >> name;
    itsName = name;
}
void carData4::setNumber(string number)
{
    cout << "Enter Your phone number (XXX)XXX-XXXX:";
    cin >> number;
    itsNumber = number;
}
int main()
{
    carData4 car1;
    int year, mileage, numCars, ;
    string make, model, name, number;

    cout << "How many vehicles are to be added to inventory?.\n\n";
    cin >> numCars;
    for (int i = 1; i < numCars; i++){
        car1.setYear(year);
        car1.setMake(make);
        car1.setModel(model);
        car1.setMileage(mileage);
        car1.setName(name);
        car1.setNumber(number);

        cout << car1.getYear() << "\t" << car1.getMake() << "\t " << car1.getModel()
            << "\t" << car1.getMileage() << "\t " << car1.getName() << "\t " << car1.getNumber() << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

i add some  is this correct????????????????

```
     int main()
  {
  carData4 car1; // *car1=new carData4[numCars];
   int year,mileage,numCars;
  double *cars;
  string make,model,name,number;  

   cout << "How many vehicles are to be added to inventory?.\n\n";
    cin >>numCars;

    cars = new double [numCars];




  for (int i=1;  i<numCars;i++){ 
  car1.setYear(year);
  car1.setMake(make);
  car1.setModel(model);
  car1.setMileage(mileage);
   car1.setName(name);
  car1.setNumber(number);

    cout << car1.getYear() << "\t" << car1.getMake() << "\t " << car1.getModel() 
      << "\t" << car1.getMileage() << "\t " <<  car1.getName() << "\t " <<      car1.getNumber()       <<endl;

     delete [] cars;
   }
   system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
```

Comment: Do you really need to allocate an **array**?  You could use `std::vector` which is an array allocated in dynamic memory.

Comment: Where do you want to have heap? Also note that arg usage in setModel is wierd and arg usage in setMileage is questionable.

Comment: I don't understand your setters.  They modify a parameter **and** they modify the class data member.  Most setters set the class data member using the parameter.

Comment: to be honest this is just a rough draft i plan on going back and clean up the junk but i was told i have to use set to get whats gonna be in private at least that is my understanding

Answer (score 2):

The best way to have dynamic storage for your use case would be to use a vector, like so:

```
std::cout << "How many vehicles are to be added to inventory?.\n\n";
std::size_t n;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<carData4> cars ( n );
//gives you:
//cars[0] ... cars[ n-1 ]
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: wont compile using this and i havent been taught that. i have read that using vector is best when you dont know how much memory you will be using.

Comment: @user3080794 using a vector is better than using a a dynamically allocated array pretty much 100% of the time, especially in general purpose programming. If you haven't learnt to use vectors I strongly recommend you go out of your way to learn them.

Comment: lol i know i need to but on my project he wants us to use array

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically allocate an array based on user input:

```
unsigned int array_capacity;
cout << "Enter array capacity: ";
cin >> array_capacity;
int * my_array = new int[array_capacity];
```

Remember to delete the array using `delete [] my_array;`.

**Edit 1: using Car class**

```
CarData4 * my_cars = new CarData4[numCars];
```

Comment: were you replacing array_capacity with numCars? we just went over  heap a week not good with it at all do i have to point (*) to any of the functions? or just in main?

Comment: The `numCars` is the variable you input from the user, which indicates the capacity of the array of `CarData4`.  If you want other functions to use the array, you must pass the array and the capacity of the array to the other functions.